# How to parse dynamic array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

I have a data coming as:

```
[
  {
    "cifId": 735960120
  }, 
  {
    "cifId": 735960121
  }
]
```

That has been received as a dynamic parameter in the route. 
I want to convert it into a `List<string>` of `cifId`.

I tried with `JObject` of `newton` and various other Options.

Here is the code with the exception below:

```
 private static List<string> GetCifIds(dynamic themeParameters)
        {



            var items = JArray.Parse(themeParameters);
            var cifIds = new List<string>();
            foreach (var dynamicCif in items)
            {
                cifIds.Add(dynamicCif.cifId.ToString());
            }

            return cifIds;


        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I tried with JObject of newton and other methods." Please *show* what you´ve tried. Don´t let us guess where your problem *might* be.

Comment: If `themeParameters` really is an array - `themeParameters.ToString()` won't give you the desired result.

Comment: What code/conversions has the data gone through to be converted from a string (or a byte array, or what) to get to the `dynamic` in the first place?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Please see the screen shot.

Comment: Please include your comment in the post instead of displaying it as a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse to JArray then walk the array:

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Q51qs)

```
private static List<string> GetCifIds(dynamic themeParameters)
{
    var items = JArray.Parse(themeParameters);
    var cifIds = new List<string>();
    foreach (var dynamicCif in items)
    {
        cifIds.Add(dynamicCif.cifId.ToString());
    }

    return cifIds;
}
```

If your json is wrongfully wrapped in `{}`, you can make it valid by removing that. Remember to check if a json is valid before parsing it. To check a json validity, you use a [json validator](https://jsonlint.com/).

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CX4n7J)

```
private static List<string> GetCifIds(dynamic themeParameters)
{
    var json = themeParameters.ToString();
    var items = JArray.Parse(json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2));
    var cifIds = new List<string>();
    foreach (var dynamicCif in items)
    {
        cifIds.Add(dynamicCif.cifId.ToString());
    }

    return cifIds;
}
```

Comment: Not working - Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] show casing your error on .netfiddle? (feel free to fork [mine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Q51qs))

Comment: @codebased I think `themeParameters` is not a string. Use a [mcve] with a proper input.

Comment: ahh I can see there is an extra { }. Why is that in webapi route is behaving like that?         public IHttpActionResult InvalidateAccountsAndCardsCache([FromBody] dynamic themeParameters, bool propagateInvalidation = false)

Comment: @codebased This json (`{[  {    ""cifId"": 735960120  }]}`) is not valid

Comment: I don't know why but I am receiving json data as  "{[  {    ""cifId"": 735960120  }]}";

Answer (score 0):

make a class like this

```
public class JsonModel
{
    public int cifId { get; set; }
}
```

And Parse your json as

```
List<int> cifIdList = new List<int>();
var jsonObj = NewtonSoft.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonModel>>(jsonString);
foreach(var elem in jsonObj){
    cifIdList.Add(elem.cifId);
}
```

All your Ids are now available in list cifIdList